# Rails: check and redirect unless boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Sounds simple, right? I've got this method in the ApplicationController:

```
def authenticate_admin
  redirect_to :root_path unless current_user.admin?
end
```

And it's called in various other controllers like so:

```
before_filter authenticate_admin
```

But I get an error that any instance variables within methods that that filter is applied to are returned nil:

```
<% @expressions.each do |expression| %>
```

Any thoughts? It seems bizarre to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing a symbol to the filter? You need to pass it a symbol. By the looks of it you are passing it a variable name, which does not exist.

```
before_filter :authenticate_admin # correct usage
```

Your example shows this:

```
before_filter authenticate_admin # incorrect
```

Notice the missing colon.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank-you. I thought I tried that before to no success.